# condition return statement Is not working with filter in rendering list of data in react.js

Tags: reactjs

** As you can see i am taking input from the user and display and wanted data display on screen according to the year which you select( filter data according to year) and if there is no item i wanted to display found no expense **
`this is my Expenses item code`

```
const ExpenseAll = (props) => {

  const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState("2020");
  const filterChangeHandler = (selectedYear) => {
    setFilteredYear(selectedYear);
  };
  const filteredExpenses = props.items.filter((expense) => {
    return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilter
          selected={filteredYear}
          onChangeFilter={filterChangeHandler}
        />
        <ExpensesList items={filteredExpenses} />
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is my condition filter code which is not working showing empty screen

```
 if (props.items.length === 0) {
   return <h2 className="expenses-list__fallback"> Found no Expense</h2>;
    }
    return (
      <ul className="expenses-list">
        {props.items.map((expense) => (
          <ExpenseItem
            key={expense.id}
            title={expense.title}
            amount={expense.amount}
            date={expense.date}
          />
        ))}{" "}
        ;
      </ul>
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store `filteredExpenses` in a state with default value:

```
const ExpenseAll = (props) => {
    const [filteredExpenses, setFilteredExpenses] = useState([]);
  const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState('2020');
  
  const filterChangeHandler = (selectedYear) => {
    setFilteredYear(selectedYear);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = props.items.filter((expense) => {
        return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear;
      });

    setFilteredExpenses(filtered)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className='expenses'>
        <ExpensesFilter
          selected={filteredYear}
          onChangeFilter={filterChangeHandler}
        />
        <ExpensesList items={filteredExpenses} />
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```